# Django: Form with multiple inputs is invalid

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

My template html has the following inputs (multiple):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="image_field" type="file">
<input name="image_field" type="file">
```

My view is:

```
def add_listing(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image_form = ImageForm(request.FILES)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('image_field')
        if image_form.is_valid():
            if object = Object.create() # since all images should relate to this object e.g. this object is the foreign key
                for f in files: # add images
                    Image.objects.create(pk=None, object=object, image=f)
                object.save()

    return render(request, 'dashboard/add_listing.html', {'image_form': image_form})
```

Forms.py

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
    class Meta:
     model = ListingImage
     fields = ['image', ]
```

Some debugging output:

```
(Pdb) image_form.is_valid()
False
(Pdb) files
[<InMemoryUploadedFile: WhatsApp Image 2018-04-08 at 20.11.17.jpeg (image/jpeg)>]
(Pdb)
```

My goal is to process the form which can take `n` inputs with the same name, and for each file in the input, validate it and create an object.

Comment: What is your debug output?

Comment: You never call `is_valid()` in that view. How do you know it is not valid?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Apologies, I've missed it out when copying. I had 2 forms (The other is used to create the object and is valid)

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov What do you mean? `pdb` returns `image_form.is_valid()` as `false`. Otherwise, there are no errors in the URL itself, because it still renders the template

Answer (score 0):

I needed to replace `image_form = ImageForm(request.FILES)`

with
`image_form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`.

I'm not sure why this was required as the `listing_form` contains only File field, and any explanation would be appreciated!